# Replace letter before space oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have different strings and I need to change a specific character if its at the end of each word
For example  input string 'atyu auds aseu udae' to be 'aty* auds ase* udae' it will replace letter u only if it was last digit need it in oracle sql

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not here to do your work for you. You need to study the the issue on your own first, try things out, study the problem, search on the internet and if you cannot find the answer after a lot of efforts spent, come here, and explain what you did, what you expected to happen, and what has happened instead.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use regular expression, such as

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'atyu auds aseu udaeu' from dual)
  3  select trim(regexp_replace(col, 'u |u$', '* ')) result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------------------
aty* auds ase* udae*

SQL>
```